# OAuth 2.0 how store token in clientside WebAPI

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I should write middleware Web API. My API should accept POST from our inner WinForm application and make POST to Web API which not belong to us. Outter WebAPI have OAuth 2.0 server side.

I think it's very bad practice to request token on each POST request. Token lifetime is 3 min.
And that's why I think it's very bad: our WinForm app is sending first post on api side we don't have token so we "redirect" this post to outer web api and recieve 401 error. Then in Controller we handle this response  and sending request to get token. And repeating first request and processing response. Problem is we waste time to get tokens.

Another way is to save token to DB and query it on each request and if token is not equal then update it.

I think I'm doing something wrong. Could somebody describe what is the good way to temporary save token.

Comment: Store it in a secure cookie in the client, and check the expiry time before making the call to decide whether to first refresh the token

Comment: You have a two port application.  Port 1 is from client to server.  Port 2 is from server to database.  So the credentials from client has to be passed at server from Port 1 to Port 2.  You do not want to store credentials where hackers can get access to the credentials if connection close.  So sending credentials with each post make the application secure from hackers.